# Difference between QPushButton and QToolButton

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton, qtoolbutton

I'm new to Qt and the difference between `QPushButton` and `QToolButton` is not so clear to me.

I know that a `QToolButton` is usually used in a `QToolBar` and it usually shows only an icon, without text, but I don't quite understand the main difference between both.

Does it have any bigger difference?
When should I use `QPushButton` and when should I use `QToolButton`?

I would like to know this to use the most appropriate button, and I need to perform some GUI tests and maybe it can be relevant.

Comment: You explained the difference yourself: one is meant for being used in a tool bar, the other as a ordinary button in the UI (for instance in a dialog you'd have "OK" and "Cancel" buttons). Do you have a specific UI / UX question that you're not asking?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`QPushButton` is simply a button. `QToolButton` is part of a group of widgets in the QtWidgets module that operate on `QAction`s: `QMenu` and `QToolBar` are other examples. As a result, `QToolButton` is much more complex under the hood than `QPushButton`.

Some examples of how they are different in practice:

- `QToolButton` is tightly integrated with `QAction`. Changing the icon, text, or other properties of a tool button's default action is reflected on the button.
- You can change the layout of the tool button contents (icon only, text only, text beside icon, text below icon). This is not possible for a `QPushButton`.
- `QToolButton` supports a "split" button type: a sidebar hot zone opens a menu instead of triggering the default action.
- Tool buttons can be created directly in a `QToolBar` by adding an action. Other widgets must be explicitly added to the toolbar.
- A tool button is meant to be displayed in a grid, so it has smaller default internal margins than a push button.
- `QPushButton` is more for "Ok"/"Close" type buttons that contain text with an optional icon.
- A `QToolButton` should generally have an icon.
- A `QPushButton` should always have text.

Answer (score 8):

From the Qt documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbutton.html#details

> A tool button is a special button that provides quick-access to specific commands or options. As opposed to a normal command button, a tool button usually doesn't show a text label, but shows an icon instead.

When I want a button in the GUI with an icon only, I use QToolButton. When I want a classic button, I use QPushButton.

No big differences.